# If range of a projection is contained in another, then the first one is dominated by the second

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-algebras, projection

I want to prove the converse of my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4093198/range-of-projections). Namely, if $H$ is a Hilbert space and $P,Q$ are projections in $\mathcal{B}(H)$ satisfying $\text{range }P\subseteq \text{range }Q$, then $P\leq Q$, i.e., $\langle x,Px\rangle \leq \langle x,Qx\rangle$ for all $x\in H$.

**My attempt:** Using the hypothesis, I'm able to show that $QP=P$ and so $PPP=PQP$. Therefore $P(Q-P)P=0$. But how to show $P\leq Q$ from this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if we prove that $Q-P$ is a projection, then $\langle x,Qx\rangle-\langle x,Px\rangle=\langle x,(Q-P)x\rangle\geq 0$.

Now, $Q-P$ is obviously self-adjoint so all we have to do is check that $Q-P$ is idempotent:

$$
(Q-P)^2=Q^2+P^2-QP-PQ=Q-PQ,
$$
using what you've already proven. Hence, we're done if we can prove that $PQ=P$. However,  $(PQ)^*=QP=P$, so $PQ=P^*=P.$

Comment: Actually, $QP=P$, but you have used $QP=Q$.

Comment: Where? I've used $Q^2+P^2-QP-PQ=Q+P-P-PQ=Q-PQ$.

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry!$\,$

Answer (score 2):

$x=Qy+z$ for some $y$ and some $ z\perp range (Q)$. Note that $z \perp range (P)$ also. Now $Px=PQy+Pz$ and $Pz=0$ because $z \perp range (P)$. Hence, $Px=PQy$. Also, $Qx=Q(Qy+z)=Q^2y=Qy$ so we have $Px=PQy=PQx$. Since $\|Q\| \leq 1$ we get  $\|Px\|^{2} \leq \|Qx\|^{2}$ which gives $ \langle Px, x \rangle \leq  \langle Qx, x \rangle$.

Comment: Why is $z \bot \text{range } P$ and $\|Q\|\leq 1$? In fact, since $Q=Q^2$, so $\|Q\|=\|Q^2\|\leq \|Q\|\|Q\|$, so $\|Q\|\geq 1$.

Comment: @Guest On the other hand, if $x=Qy+z$, as above, you have $Qx=Qy$, implying that $\|Q\|\leq 1$.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Why does $Qx=Qy$ imply $\|Q\|\leq 1$?

Comment: Because $\|x\|^2=\|Qy\|^2+\|z\|^2$ by orthogonality.

Comment: $z \perp range (P)$ because range of $P$ is contained in range of $Q$. For any (non-zero) projection $Q$ we have $\|Q\|=1$. I suppose you are considering orthogonal projections on a Hilbert space. @Guest

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Why does the relation between the range imply $z\bot \text{range }P$?

Comment: Do you know what orthogonality means? If $z$ is orthogonal to every element of range of $Q$ then it is  orthogonal to every element of range of $P$  becasue the latter is contained in the former. @Guest